# Special case of Plancherel's implies Plancherel's

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Please note that 1) My analysis background is weak, so things that may be "obvious" are likely not obvious to me. 2) My question is not "how to prove Plancharel's". I know there is much information on this available online.

In my course we have proven that Plancherel's holds for Schwartz functions (rapidly decreasing functions), that is $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ then $\lVert \hat{f} \rVert_{2} = \sqrt{2\pi} \, \lVert{f}\rVert_{2}$, where the constant is just because of our normalization of the Fourier Transform.

I would like to prove that more generally this result holds for functions in $L^{1} \cap L^{2}$. We have proven in class that $\mathcal{S}(R)$ is dense in $L^{1} \cap L^{2}$ so for some $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$ I know I could choose some sequence of Schwartz functions, $(\phi_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $$\phi_j \to f \tag{in $L^1$ and $L^2$ norm?},$$ then I also know by Riemann-Lesbegue that this implies $$\hat{\phi_j} \to \hat{f} \tag{uniformly, in $\infty$ norm?}$$

But then how can I use this information (and possibly other facts) to show that Plancherel's holds for $f$ as well?

Comment: The Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma gives that $|\hat{\phi_j}(\xi) - \hat{f}(\xi)|\to 0$ as $|\xi|\to\infty$. It's a statement about the limit of a function, in the regular calculus sense.
Now, the best way to think of your question is in the abstract case of Banach spaces. Check this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890913/how-do-you-extend-an-isometry-from-a-dense-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cauchy sequences ; $||\phi_j -\phi_k||_2 \leq ||\phi_j -f||_2 +||f -\phi_k||_2 \to 0$. Hence $||\hat \phi_j - \hat \phi_k ||_2 \to 0$. Now $||\phi_j -f||_1 \to 0$ and this implies $\hat \phi_j - \hat f \to 0$ pointwise because $|\hat {h}| \leq ||h||_1$ (upto a factor of $\sqrt {2\pi}$) for any $L^{1}$ function h. The fact that $\{ \hat {\phi_j}\}$ is Cauchy in $L^{2}$ implies it converges in $L^{2}$ and since this sequence converges pointwise to $\hat f$ it follows that $\hat \phi_j \to \hat f$ in $L^{2}$. ( $L^{2}$ convergence implies pointwise  convergence almost everywhere for a subsequence so the pointwise and $L^{2}$ limits coincide). Now just take limits in $||\hat \phi_j||_2 =\sqrt {2\pi} ||\phi_j||_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In the final line, when I “just take limits” - the idea is I want to say I can bring those limits inside the norm? Which fact from the argument above let’s me say lim || f_j ||_2 = || lim f_j ||_2 ? Sorry for typesetting I’m on my phone

Comment: I am just using the fact that $||g_n -g||_2 \to 0$ implies $||g_n|| _2\to ||g||_2$. This is a universal truth for any norm. No interchange of limit and integral is involved here.

Comment: Is there a name of this result, or something I could look up to see that fact?

Comment: This is just triangle inequality: in any normed  linear space $||x_n-x|| \to 0$ implies $||x_n|| \leq ||x_n -x||+||x|| < \epsilon +||x||$ and $||x|| \leq ||x-x_n|| +||x_n|| <\epsilon + ||x_n||$ for n sufficiently large. Putting these two together we get $||x_n|| \to ||x||$.